# Optional parameters at the beginning of route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

I'm trying to create a route that satisfies below two scenarios:

1. en-us/mycontroller/action/1
2. mycontroller/action/1

Basically what I need is the below rule. But it seems that the system is always expecting the locale parameter, even though it's optional.

```
[Route("{locale?}/[controller]/[action]")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
     [Route("{id}")]
     public IActionResult Action(int id) {
          return View();
     }
}
```

Any idea how I can create a rule that supports above scenarios?

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to put as optional an action you should use two endpoints for this

Comment: What if you have a controller called "en-us"? How will the route engine tell the difference?

Comment: This is a very bad idea.  A URI is a resource identifier, so it should have a relationship built into it.  Use to methods in your controller and specify the routes at the action level.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  If you need to share code based on country or language, then move your business logic in a business layer.  This should be your architecture anyways.  Then separate your controllers or move these into two different applications and reference the shared DLL (maybe from an internal NuGet feed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optional parameters in routes must be at the end. There's no way around that. However, there's an alternate way to handle it: just add multiple routes:

```
[Route("{locale}/[controller]/[action]")]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
```

Now it will respond to either way. FWIW, you might want to consider adding some constraints to the `locale` param, though, so it doesn't match *everything*.